# How to convert this javascript code to lightning

Tags: lightning

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js")}

var r = confirm("Are you sure?");
if(r == true)
{
sforce.apex.execute("psaPTO_Accrual","calculatePTOForAllResources",{String:"String"});
alert("The PTO Accrual batch has been initiated. You will receive an email when batch processing is complete!");
}

parent.frames.location.reload();
```

Comment: One of the options could be to create a lightning component, which will all an auraenabled method, which  will execute given method (calculatePTOForAllResources) from mentioned (psaPTO_Accrual) class with desired parameters

Answer (score 1):

> Transform Your JavaScript Buttons with the Lightning Experience
>   Configuration Converter

1. [Lightning Experience Configuration Converter JavaScript Button Conversion Types](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lcc_javascript_buttons_conversion_types.htm&type=5)
2. [Convert and Deploy a JavaScript Button or Link as a Simpler Button or Link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lcc_javascript_buttons_convert_to_button_or_link.htm&type=5)
3. [Convert and Deploy a JavaScript Button as a Full Lightning Component Action](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lcc_javascript_buttons_convert_to_lc_full.htm&type=5)
4. [Convert a JavaScript Button into a Partial Lightning Component Action](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lcc_javascript_buttons_convert_to_lc_partial.htm&type=5)
5. [When the Lightning Experience Configuration Converter Can’t Convert Your JavaScript Buttons or Links](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lcc_javascript_buttons_overview.htm&type=5)
6. [Lightning Experience Configuration Converter Considerations for JavaScript Buttons](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lcc_considerations_js.htm&type=5)
7. [Deep dive to lightning alternative for JavaScript button](https://success.salesforce.com/0693A000007KfEd?retUrl=%2F_ui%2Fcore%2Fchatter%2Fcontent%2FGroupFileListPage)

In your scenario, You can use init handler to confirm and based on response you can execute apex method.

[Invoking Actions on Component Initialization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_init_handler.htm) would help you to understand init handler.

[Calling a Server-Side Action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm) will help you to understand executing an apex method via lightning component.